# repartition and sort within partition and custom partitioner in spark giving array out of bound exception

Tags: apache-spark, partitioner

6
I tried to implement what is explained [here](http://codingjunkie.net/spark-secondary-sort/). It is working when i keep number of partition in custom partition equal to one but when i change this keep any other value it gives out array out of bound exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, deenbandhu): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:920)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:918)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:918)
at DataSetCreation$.main(CreateDataSet.scala:100)
at DataSetCreation.main(CreateDataSet.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am unable to figure it out what is causing this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2` Where do you call arrays in your code? And where do you generate indexes? I've given a look to the tutorial you're following: did you change something?

Comment: i have found the problem please refer to my solution thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue in my Custom partitoner when calculating hashcode and getting partition number it is giving negative number and hence giving array out of bound error now i have taken the absolute value and it is working fine now.